# Efficiently convert unsigned to signed

Tags: c, optimization, casting, c99

I always subtract by 32768 when I have an unsigned short that I want to convert to a signed one.

Is that the fastest way to do it, or are there faster ways?

Comment: Is that even a *correct* way?! If I want to convert `0`, then by your scheme I end up with `-32768`?

Comment: Yes, so now you get -32767. Much better.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what "convert" means to you.

Comment: This the reason we use compiler for...

Comment: @NikosC. Fitting an unsigned int into a signed one. Without applying the 32768 offset, you will loose the upper half.

Comment: What you want to do is re-origin the value, not "cast" it.

Comment: @HotLicks AKA reinterpret the bits as having signed type.

Comment: This conversion should not be called a cast. Casts preserve the cast-from value when possible, that's their purpose. What is the purpose of your conversion?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze - No, that would be a cast.  If you take unsigned 5 and cast it to signed you get 5, not -32763.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value is between from 0 to `SHRT_MAX` (inclusive), there's nothing to worry about and the cast (`(short)`) is optional (unless your compiler is paranoid or configured to be paranoid).

If the `unsigned short` value can be greater than `SHRT_MAX`, about the only legal way to convert it to `short` is:

```
#include <limits.h>

short ushort2short(unsigned short s)
{
  if (s <= SHRT_MAX)
    return s; // or return (short)s;
  s -= SHRT_MAX + 1; // now s is 0 ... SHRT_MAX
  return (short)s - SHRT_MAX - 1;
}
```

This, of course, relies on signed shorts being 2's complement with `SHRT_MIN` = -`SHRT_MAX` - 1.

A modern compiler will optimize away all the nonsense inside this function and just generate code to return `s`.

**EDIT**: Compiled the above with gcc 4.6.2 as `gcc -Wall ush2sh.c -O2 -S -o ush2sh.s` to this assembly code:

```
        .file   "ush2sh.c"
        .text
        .p2align 2,,3
        .globl  _ushort2short
        .def    _ushort2short;  .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
_ushort2short:
LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        movl    4(%esp), %eax
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
LFE0:
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your last sentence. That's asking a lot from the compiler. Have you looked at the disassembly?

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed... Now that I look at it again, I can see how the compiler can do it with just the standard optimization passes. At first glance it looked it would require data-range analysis, which is something that many compilers lack.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze If it can be done in a single assembly instruction, why cannot I do without a helper-procedure in C?

Comment: Your compiler may be smart enough to avoid generating code for a separate function and code for calling it. Try and see.